# Provisioning profile not installing to device

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I'm attempting to install a provisioning profile to an iPad Air 2 (iOS ver. 11.0.3). However, none of the methods I've tried have made the profile appear under the devices 'Profiles & Device Management' section. I've attempted the following:

1. Syncing the file using iTunes (12.6.3.6) via 'Add File to Library...'
2. Opening a URL within Safari that links to the profile. Doing this displays a prompt asking if I would like the view the configuration profile in my devices settings. Selecting 'Allow' takes me to 'Profiles & Device Management' but again the profile isn't added nor am I even prompted to review the profile.

Note: I do not have access to a Mac so I cannot use Xcode or Apple Configurator to load the profile.